# apt-cyg, where the downloaded files stored?

Tags: cygwin, apt-get

When I use the command 'apt-cyg install package-name' and once the Cygwin has downloaded the package it says 'package-name saved'. I can't seem to find this in the hard drive though. So where is it located?

Comment: I'm not using apt-cyg, I do it with the normal setup. If that program follows apt-get, it stores the packages in /var/lib/apt. If the manpage doesn't tell the location, you could run the program with `strace` to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found them inside /setup and inside a folder with the name of the mirror used to download the packages